# Grails deployment using run-war throws exception

Tags: grails

Environment: Windows 7, JDK1.7, GGTS 3.6.1, database: Postgres 9.3, Grails 2.4.3

The System seems to up and running fine when used with run-app.
When I use the run-war it builds the war file and during running the application it throws up exception, attached below. (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class grails.util.Holders)
When I looked in to the buildconfig.groovy and removed couple of entries that were added by me for the dependencies of jar files that were needed by this application. These Jars are developed by me and have the product specific code. Once removed the system started up with out any exception.
These jars have java class files (not groovy),These are developed using JDK 1.7.
These class files are used in the application (product specific)
The postgres database has been added instead of the default database.
The dependent jars are part of the repo that we have in house.
Just to make sure that it was not a problem with the application, i created a sample application and tried run-war; it seemed to work fine. When I added these dependent jar entries in the build config it started to throw the exception. The repo url has been used in the build config for the dependent jars

Exception:

```
Error | SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
Error | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/software/grails-2.4.3/dist/grails-plugin-log4j-2.4.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
Error | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/<loc>/<applicationName>/target/work/tomcat/webapps/<applicationName>/WEB-INF/lib/grails-plugin-log4j-2.4.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
Error | SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Error | SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory]
Error | log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
Error | log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Error | log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class grails.util.Holders
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class grails.util.Holders
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Error listenerStart
Context [/<applicationName>] startup failed due to previous errors
The web application [/<applicationName>] registered the JDBC driver [org.h2.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
The web application [/<applicationName>] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

Answer (score 0):

`NoClassDefFoundError` is typically tedious to fix. It's easily confused with `ClassNotFoundException` but it's very different. If you get a `ClassNotFoundException` you have the name of the class that it was trying to load but couldn't find. That's usually easy to fix - find the jar that contains it, and add a dependency for it, resolve it from the Maven repo that it's deployed to, and get back to work.

But `NoClassDefFoundError` happens when a class you're trying to load cannot find a class or resource that it depends on. Knowing the class name is often not very helpful, and that's certainly true here - `Holders` is a Grails class that's obviously in your classpath. Weirdly all of its dependencies are of course also in the classpath, so it's probably a few jars away.

But since you've manually added jars to the lib directory, it's most likely that you missed a dependency of one of them. Look at your imports and try to find what's missing. It could be something trivial that's not really important for what you're trying to do. But if a class that is indirectly related to it fails to load, you need to ensure that it's there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried the following; I ran the command "grails dev war" that created the war file, exploded the same. I ran the command "grails dependency-report" and manually verified that all the jars needed by the project are available. Even the jars indirectly needed (jars needed by jars). How is the grails system able to resolve the same during run-app and not during run-war ?

Comment: The issue got resolved. The jar needed by the application used Spring as a dependency and this was of a different version. So the class path took the Spring version from the jar and messed up the start up.